# Is there any relationship between Kush's son Havilah, and/or Shem's descendant with the same name, and the area called Havilah?

Tags: genesis-bereishith

Bereishis 2:11 says "שֵׁ֥ם הָֽאֶחָ֖ד פִּישׁ֑וֹן ה֣וּא הַסֹּבֵ֗ב אֵ֚ת כׇּל־אֶ֣רֶץ **הַֽחֲוִילָ֔ה** אֲשֶׁר־שָׁ֖ם הַזָּהָֽב׃"

Bereishis 10:7 lists Kush's descendants "וּבְנֵ֣י כ֔וּשׁ סְבָא֙ **וַֽחֲוִילָ֔ה** וְסַבְתָּ֥ה וְרַעְמָ֖ה וְסַבְתְּכָ֑א וּבְנֵ֥י רַעְמָ֖ה שְׁבָ֥א וּדְדָֽן׃"

Also, Shem has a descendant with this name, Bereishis 10:29 "וְאֶת־אוֹפִ֥ר **וְאֶת־חֲוִילָ֖ה** וְאֶת־יוֹבָ֑ב כׇּל־אֵ֖לֶּה בְּנֵ֥י יׇקְטָֽן׃"

Shmuel 15:7 refers to Havilah as a place Amalek comes from. That's as far as I got.

Comment: Many modern scholars think that the table of nations in Genesis represents areas of the world.